# Handle command line arguments?

Tags: c, unix, command-line-arguments

So, I can make my program run and all, but if I'm given

```
$ ./a.out -f Text.txt
```

I'm just not sure how to get the program to make the connection that -f indicates a file. What is the logic for doing this?

Comment: Look up the "getopt()" function in the C runtime ("man getopt" if you're on a Unix box).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `main`  function has signature `int main(int argc, char**argv)`; so you can use the `argc` (which is positive) & `argv` arguments. The `argv` array is guaranteed to have `argc+1` elements. The last is always `NULL`. The others are non-nil, non-aliased zero-byte terminated strings. Notice that often some [shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) is [globbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29) the arguments before your program is started by [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html): see [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html).

For example, if you type (in a Linux terminal) `myprog -i a*.c -o foo.txt` and if at the moment you type that the shell has expanded (by [globbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29)) `a*.c` into `a1.c` and `a2.c` (because these are the only files whose name start with `a` and have a `.c` suffix in the current directory), your `myprog` executable `main` program is called with

- `argc==6`
- `argv[0]` containing `"myprog"` (so you could test that `strcmp(argv[0],"myprog") == 0`)
- `argv[1]` containing `"-i"`
- `argv[2]` containing `"a1.c"`
- `argv[3]` containing `"a2.c"`
- `argv[4]` containing `"-o"`
- `argv[5]` containing `"foo.txt"`
- `argv[6]` being the `NULL` pointer

In addition you are guaranteed (by the kernel doing the [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html)) that all the 6 `argv` pointers are distinct, non-[aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_aliasing), and non-overlapping.

GNU libc gives you [several ways](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Program-Arguments.html#Program-Arguments) to parse these arguments: [getopt](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html#Getopt) & [argp](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argp.html#Argp). [getopt](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/functions/getopt.html) is standardized in POSIX (but GNU gives you also the very useful [getopt_long(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html))

I strongly suggest you to follow [GNU conventions](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html#Command_002dLine-Interfaces): accept at least `--help` and `--version`

The fact that e.g. `-f` is for some option and not a file name is often conventional (but see use of `--` in program arguments). If you happen to really want a *file* named `-f` (which is a very bad idea), use `./-f`

Several shells have [autocompletion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocomplete). You need to configure them for that (and you might configure them even for your own programs).