# How to pass run time arguments to a function in c through a shell script

Tags: c, linux, function, shell, command-line

I have a shell script which has to take arguments from the command line and pass it to a function in C. I tried to search but didn't find understandable solutions. Kindly help me out.
Should the arguments be passed via an option as a command in the shell script?

I have a main function like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc>1)
    {
        if(!strcmp(argv[1], "ABC"))
        {



        }
        else if(!strcmp(argv[1], "XYZ"))   
        {

        }
    }
}
```

How to pass the parameters ABC/XYZ from the command line through a shell script which in turn uses a makefile to compile the code?

Comment: On which operating system?

Comment: Compile your program with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Then [use the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/)

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch: Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Don't comment your question, but edit it to improve it. My answer should then be completely relevant for Ubuntu (or any other Linux distribution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot meaningfully compare strings with `==`  which is a pointer equality test. You could use [strcmp](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) as something like `argc>1 && !strcmp(argv[1], "XYZ")`. The arguments of `main` have certain properties, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26534525/841108).

BTW, `main`'s `argc` is at least 1. So your test `argc==0` is *never* true. Generally `argv[0]` is the program name.

However, if you use [GNU glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) (e.g. on Linux), it provides several ways for [parsing program arguments](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Program-Arguments.html).

There are [conventions and habits](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Program-Arguments.html) regarding program arguments, and you'll better follow them. POSIX specifies [getopt(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html), but on GNU systems, [`getopt_long`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html) is even more handy.

Be also aware that [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) is done by the [shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) on Unix-like systems. See [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html).

<sup>(On Windows, things are different, and the command line might be parsed by some startup routine à la [crt0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0))</sup>

In practice, you'll better use some system functions for parsing program arguments. Some libraries provide a way for that, e.g. [GTK](http://gtk.org/) has [`gtk_init_with_args`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-General.html#gtk-init-with-args). Otherwise, if you have it, use `getopt_long` ...

Look also, for inspiration, into the source code of some [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) program. You'll find many of them on [github](http://github.com/) or elsewhere.

> How to pass the parameters ABC/XYZ from the command line through a shell script

If you compile your C++ program into an [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable), e.g. `/some/path/to/yourexecutable`, you just have to run a command like

```
 /some/path/to/yourexecutable ABC
```

and if the directory `/some/path/to/` containing `yourexecutable` is in your [`PATH` variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)), you can simply run `yourexecutable ABC`. How to set that `PATH` variable (which you can query using `echo $PATH` in your [Unix shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell)) is a different question (you could edit some shell [startup](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html) file, perhaps your `$HOME/.bashrc`, with a [source code editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_editor) such as [GNU `emacs`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/), [`vim`](http://vim.org/), `gedit`, etc...; you could run some `export PATH=`.... command with an appropriate, colon-separated, sequence of directories).

> which in turn uses a makefile to compile the code?

Then you should look into that `Makefile` and you'll know what is the executable file.

---

You are using and coding on/for Linux, so you should read something about Linux programming (e.g. [ALP](http://www.cse.hcmut.edu.vn/~hungnq/courses/nap/alp.pdf) or something newer; see also [intro(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/intro.2.html) & [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)...) and you need to understand more about operating systems (so read [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/)).

Comment: Not that much (less than a dozen, and most of them are to local files). I usually google them.....

Comment: The comments have been taken in. Thanks

Comment: Feel free to accept my answer (checkbox on left of it).

Comment: I have reframed the question, kindly help me out

Answer (score 2):

See following simple example:

```
$ cat foo.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < argc; ++i) {
        printf("[%d] %s\n", i, argv[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
$ gcc foo.c
$ ./a.out foo bar
[0] ./a.out
[1] foo
[2] bar
$
```

Comment: Got the solution. Thanks a lot